# EmguCV, native memory leaks

Tags: c#, opencv, memory-leaks, emgucv

I use EmguCV (various versions) and after running example application (LicensePlateRecognition), I noticed that even though I force garbage collection and dispose the license plate detector object, the program still uses 450MB memory while idling (after processing image, seen in Windows Resource Manager). It happens with other examples too. I guess it's a native memory leak. .Net Memory Profiler shows that most data is allocated in Kernel->HeapMemory.

Why Emgu allocates so much memory and can I somehow free that memory? All OpenCV ddls are ~400MB. Is it just bad wrapping? I used OpenCV library from the right package.

The thing is when I tried running, for example, face detection on multiple cameras simultaneously, I get error "failed to allocate XXX bytes". Can Emgu handle more than one (at least low resolution) cameras? I quickly run out of memory.

Comment: Interesting. I've recently made an tiny opencv native c++ wrapper to use in .NET  managed code for myself in which I had to pass images between managed and unmanaged code ie read them in c++ part, process them and pass to .NET part. Of course my wrapper is using c++ opencv dlls which are loaded into memory. And I indeed noticed quite big memory consumption as you noticed with EmguCV (which might have similar architecture to my wrapper). I can investigate memory consumption of my wrapper more in numbers if you want more details.

Comment: @marol I would love to hear more feedback.

Comment: So give me some time and I will come back with the results.